# Incomplete object data upon retrieving from its array

Tags: solidity, remix

When I retrieve an **item** object from the **item** array, the remix compiler doesn't show me one
of the attributes of the **item** object, which is an array of a struct. This is the code, assume that the **globalFarmers** array has some data stored in it.

```
pragma solidity >=0.5.0 <0.6.0;
import "./farm.sol";
import "./manufacturer.sol";
contract Test is Farm, Manufacturer{

struct Item {

Farmer[] farmers;

string manufacturerName;
string manufacturerDate;

string distributorDate;
string distributorName;
}


Farmer [] public globalFarmers;
Item[] public items;
```

This is the only function that can add data for now.

```
function addManufacturerData(uint[] memory _farmerIds, string memory _name,
 string memory _date) public {

     items.length++;
     Item storage tempItem = items[items.length-1];
     for(uint i = 0 ; i<_farmerIds.length; i++){
         tempItem.farmers.push(globalFarmers[_farmerIds[i]]);
     }

     tempItem.manufacturerName = _name;
     tempItem.manufacturerDate = _date;

}
```

The code compiles fine and here is the output when I fetch the **item** object from its array.

[image: Remix response on retrieving the item from its array]

Why the Farmer array is missing in the response?

Answer (score 0):

Solidity does not know how to encode structs while returning them from a function by default.

Try adding:

```js
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;
```

Take a look at this example:

https://medium.com/@dillonsvincent/solidity-enable-experimental-abiencoderv2-to-use-a-struct-as-function-parameter-27979603a879